# Python, lxml - access text

Tags: python, text, html-parsing, lxml

I m currently a bit out of ideas, and I really hope that you can give me a hint:
Its probably best to explain my question with a small piece of sample code:

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

testStr = "<b>text0<i>text1</i><ul><li>item1</li><li>item2</li></ul>text2<b/><b>sib</b>"
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
# generate html tree
htmlTree   = etree.parse(StringIO(testStr), parser)
print(etree.tostring(htmlTree, pretty_print=True).decode("utf-8"))
bElem = htmlTree.getroot().find("body/b") 
print(".text only contains the first part: "+bElem.text+ " (which makes sense in some way)")
for text in bElem.itertext():
    print(text)
```

**Output:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <body>
    <b>text0<i>text1</i><ul><li>item1</li><li>item2</li></ul>text2<b/><b>sib</b></b>
  </body>
</html>

.text only contains the first part: text0 (which makes sense in some way)
text0
text1
item1
item2
text2
sib
```

**My Question:**

I would like to access `"text2"` directly, or get a list of all text parts, only including the ones that can be found in the parent tag.
So far I only found `itertext()`, which does display `"text2"`.

Is there any other way I could retrieve `"text2"`?

Now you might be asking why I need this:
Basically `itertext()` is pretty much already doing what I want:

- Create a list, that contains all text found in an element's children
- However, I want to process tables and lists that are encountered with
  a different function (which subsequently creates a list structure
  like this: `["text0 text1",["item1","item2"],"text2"]` or for a table (1. Row with 1 Column, 2.
  Row with 2 Columns): `["1. row, 1 col",["2. row, 1. col","2. row, 2.
  col"]]`)

Maybe I m taking a completely wrong approach?

Comment: you could use encoding=unicode with tostring()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just reimplement `itertext()` function and insert special handlers for `ul`, `table` if necessary:

```
from lxml import html

def itertext(root, handlers=dict(ul=lambda el: (list(el.itertext()),
                                                el.tail))):
    if root.text:
        yield root.text
    for el in root:
        yield from handlers.get(el.tag, itertext)(el)
    if root.tail:
        yield root.tail

print(list(itertext(html.fromstring(
                "<b>text0<i>text1</i><ul><li>item1</li>"
                "<li>item2</li></ul>text2<b/><b>sib</b>"))))
```

#### Output

```
['text0', 'text1', ['item1', 'item2'], 'text2', 'sib']
```

Note: `yield from X` could be replaced by `for x in X: yield x` on older than Python 3.3 versions.

To join adjacent strings:

```
def joinadj(iterable, join=' '.join):
    adj = []
    for item in iterable:
        if isinstance(item, str):
            adj.append(item) # save for later
        else:
            if adj: # yield items accumulated so far
                yield join(adj)
                del adj[:] # remove yielded items
            yield item # not a string, yield as is

    if adj: # yield the rest
        yield join(adj)

print(list(joinadj(itertext(html.fromstring(
                "<b>text0<i>text1</i><ul><li>item1</li>"
                "<li>item2</li></ul>text2<b/><b>sib</b>")))))
```

#### Output

```
['text0 text1', ['item1', 'item2'], 'text2 sib']
```

To allow tables, nested list in `<ul>` the handler should call `itertext()` recursively:

```
def ul_handler(el):
    yield list(itertext(el, with_tail=False))
    if el.tail:
        yield el.tail

def itertext(root, handlers=dict(ul=ul_handler), with_tail=True):
    if root.text:
        yield root.text
    for el in root:
        yield from handlers.get(el.tag, itertext)(el)
    if with_tail and root.tail:
        yield root.tail

print(list(joinadj(itertext(html.fromstring(
                    "<b>text0<i>text1</i><ul><li>item1</li>"
                    "<li>item2<ul><li>sub1<li>sub2</li></ul></ul>"
                    "text2<b/><b>sib</b>")))))
```

#### Output

```
['text0 text1', ['item1', 'item2', ['sub1', 'sub2']], 'text2 sib']
```