# convert python lxml node to string without tostring

Tags: python, lxml

Is it possible to convert lxml xpath'ed node to string without `"tostring"` function  ?

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.HTML(content)
head = tree.xpath('//head')[0]
head = etree.tostring(head)
```

Comment: Why on earth you don't want to use the provided `tostring()` function? If you need a slightly different output and it is not in a standard output format, most likely you'll need to write your own function...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, lxml - access text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677411/python-lxml-access-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, if not extremely easy.

This is similar to an earlier question, which received [an awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11678406/5339635). You should be able to use a similar implementation, tailored to whatever your needs are.